# appendTo внутри блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть html c

```
<div class="product-box-info__body__carousel__item" id="li-comment-2" data-comment-id="2">
<div class="product-box-info__body__carousel__item" id="li-comment-3" data-comment-id="3">
```

Внутри каждого нужно сделать перемещение appendTo

Js

```
    if(parentId == $('.rating').attr('data-comment-id')){
        parent.find('.rating[data-comment-id='+parentId+']').appendTo('.product-box-info__body__carousel__item__footer');
    }
```

Проблема в том что все блоки rating перемещаются в другие блоки, а не родительский

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parent.find('.rating[data-comment-id=' + parentId + ']').appendTo(
  parent.find('.product-box-info__body__carousel__item__footer')
);
```